# Could not find treetop-1.4.9 in any of the sources - cap deploy:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, rvm, treetop

I am running into an issue when trying to run migrations from capistrano (cap deploy:migrate).

```
latest => /var/www/site/releases/20110108002015
* executing "cd /var/www/site/releases/20110108002015; rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
servers: ["www.site.com"]
[www.site.com] executing command
** [out :: www.site.com] (in /var/www/site/releases/20110108002015)
** [out :: www.site.com] Could not find treetop-1.4.9 in any of the sources
** [out :: www.site.com] Try running `bundle install`.
command finished
failed: "sh -c 'cd /var/www/site/releases/20110108002015; rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate'" on www.site.com
```

The facts;

- Rails 3.0.0
- Ruby 1.9.2 via rvm

The treetop gem is installed, and if I ssh into the remote server and run the command that capistrano is attempting manually, it works without issue.

Anyone else run into this or a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you ssh onto the server and run the command, is it using the same user capistrano is deploying as? Often issues like this are due to the deploy users path not including the same folders as your path might.

Try using `cap shell` to run the command, then you can test it under the same conditions cap is under.

Comment: cap shell comes up with the same error. I have looked around the cap source files to try and get an idea of what the task entails, and I am assuming that it's using ActiveRecord but I am less sure of where Treetop fits in.